# Gigya - complete registration for an auto-generated account

Tags: javascript, gigya

Newbie to gigya. I have been trying to identify how can I achieve complete registration in my web application for an account that is generated using gigya REST api with an auto-generated details. I have the UID for that account, using which I can retrieve the user details.
My questions are:
Is it possible to complete the registration for that account(auto-generated) using the Complete Registration screen set?
If so, how can I achieve the profile completion?

Answer (score 0):

Screen-Sets are client-side, so, there is no way to use the Complete Registration screen inside a REST implementation.

Three possible solutions are:

1. *If you have the data*: Include all the necessary data properties in the call to [accounts.register](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.register+REST).
2. *If you have the data*: After registering the user, using the UID call [accounts.setAccountInfo](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.setAccountInfo+REST) and add the necessary data properties.
3. *If you **don't** have the data*: Don't do anything via REST to complete the registration info (and leave it in 'Pending' state setting **finalizeRegistration: false** in the accounts.register call. This will cause the API to return "errorCode": 206001, "errorMessage": "Account Pending Registration"). Then add the [screen-sets](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.showScreenSet+JS) to your page/app and when the user attempts to login, any required information that is missing will need to be provided via the Complete Registration screen, which will automatically fire and prompt the user for this data and then finalize the registration.

Comment: But here the auto generated username & passwords are unknown for the user. I have only UID and accessToken, where using this, I can retrieve the username.

Comment: @sadiqmc, Is this for some testing/development scenario or are you trying to implement something like this in production?

Comment: Currently am trying in development and needs to move to production once the development is success

Answer (score 0):

@sadiqmc could you explain a little bit about what you're trying to do? What's the flow that you're trying to accomplish? 

Edit:
As per your flow, you probably shouldn't use the [Update Profile](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Screen-Sets#Screen-Sets-UpdateProfileFlow) screen to let the user change their info, as the auto-generated content will be pre populated and will confuse the user.

Since you already have the UID, you can build a generic form to collect the user's data and then update the account using [setAccountInfo](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.setAccountInfo+REST).

Comment: Ok. A user is been registered to a 3rd party application using his mobile number. My middleware application registers this user with an auto-generated email, name and password in a specific format which includes his mobile number and returns a redirect URL to my web application. So while loading this redirect url, gigya complete registration screen is to be displayed. Using this screen, I need to fetch the actual user details from the user at this moment and call an update profile using the screen.

Comment: .. One thing to be noted, we have added all the required field in gigya when registering with auto-generated profile.